# Average predicted value in caret CV

Tags: r, cross-validation, r-caret, data-wrangling

I would like to get the average predicted value across CV repeats using caret in R.

```
require("caret")
data("iris")
fitControl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",   
                             number = 10,
                             repeats = 10, savePredictions = 'final')
model.cv <- train(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width,
                    data = iris,
                    method = "lm", 
                    trControl = fitControl)

head(model.cv$pred)
#  intercept     pred obs rowIndex     Resample
#1      TRUE 5.809386 4.7        3 Fold01.Rep01
#2      TRUE 5.838487 4.6        4 Fold01.Rep01
#3      TRUE 5.460174 5.7       16 Fold01.Rep01
#4      TRUE 5.634780 5.7       19 Fold01.Rep01
#5      TRUE 5.722083 5.2       28 Fold01.Rep01
#6      TRUE 6.071295 4.5       42 Fold01.Rep01
```

Now I would like to get the average of all the 10 predictions of each example. I can do it by iterating over the examples as follows but I think there has to be a better tidier way.

```
mean(model.cv$pred[model.cv$pred$rowIndex==1, "pred"])
#[1] 5.745675
```

**EDIT**

Following @Obim's answer, I tested the timings of the three proposed solutions. The `dplyr` version is way faster. Note that I slightly modified the `sapply` version by adding a sort over the unique `rowINdex` to keep its output consistent and interpretable.

```
library("plyr")
library("dplyr")
library("tictoc")

tic("plyr")
for(i in 1:100) meansplyr = ddply(model.cv$pred, ~rowIndex, summarise, mean = mean(pred))
toc()
#plyr: 5.56 sec elapsed

tic("dplyr")
for(i in 1:100) meansdplyr = model.cv$pred %>% group_by(rowIndex) %>% summarise(pred = mean(pred))
toc()
#dplyr: 0.08 sec elapsed

tic("sapply")
for(i in 1:100) {
  meanssapply = sapply(
  X = sort(unique(model.cv$pred$rowIndex)), # added sort to keep the output consistent
  FUN = function(x){mean(model.cv$pred$pred[model.cv$pred$rowIndex %in% x])}
  )
}
toc()
#sapply: 0.73 sec elapsed

# the outputs are exactly the same
sum(abs(meansplyr$mean - meansdplyr$pred))
#[1] 0

sum(abs(meansplyr$mean - meanssapply))
#[1] 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One liner with ddply:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(model.cv$pred, ~rowIndex, summarise, mean = mean(pred))
```

Or with dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
model.cv$pred %>% 
  group_by(rowIndex) %>% 
  summarise(pred = mean(pred))
```

Another way with sapply (although still iterating over each rowIndex). As @DataD'Oh pointed out, the input should be sorted to allow interpretation of the output:

```
sapply(
  X = sort(unique(model.cv$pred$rowIndex)), 
  FUN = function(x){mean(model.cv$pred$pred[model.cv$pred$rowIndex %in% x])}
)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, this is what I was looking for. I have done simple time tests and it shows the dplyr version to be the fastest and the plyr to be way slower. Maybe you can add that to your answer which will make it much more comprehensive.

Comment: for the sapply version the X needs to be sorted to keep the outputs consistent

Comment: Great! Thanks for the details. I'm new here, so I'm not sure if I should still edit my answer, or if your own edit is sufficient. I'm assuming the latter.

Comment: I think you should edit your sapply version to "correct" it.